# Spring XD on YARN: not able to stream kafka source to hdfs sink

Tags: spring-xd

Spring XD on YARN: not able to stream kafka source to hdfs sink

I have a proper HDFS Resource Manager up and running.
I'm able to bring up Admin server and containers successfully in YARN.

But I'm not able to stream Kafka(source) to HDFS(sink)

I configured the custom modules provided for Kafka(source) and hdfs(sink).
But when I produce a kafka message for a topic, nothing is happening in the YARN cluster.

Setup details:

HDFS / YARN apache version 2.6.0

Spring XD on YARN --- spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE-yarn.zip

Comment: Have you checked xd admin/container logs for errors?

Comment: Hi Jane, I checked all the Yarn container log folders and do not see any errors. all containers including admin are running fine. Also the in the xd shell, 'admininfo' is listing out the admin server url. I added custom modules of kafka as source and hdfs as sink. These custom modules I picked up from spring-xd-release.zip and made appropriate changes like zookeeper address and topic name.

Comment: If you use build-in kafka source and hdfs sink you don't need to play with custom modules(or do you have a real custom module?). Maybe this has something to do with the problem. You could add changed configuration, used stream command and how you actually tested sending something to kafka to the question.

Comment: Jane,
 I tried with built in kafka source and hdfs sink after making the corresponding configuration in $XD_HOME/config/servers.yml.Still I did not see 
 incoming kafka message stored in hdfs.
 
 Based on your response(...used stream command...), I have one basic question.
 Even in Spring XD on YARN, can we create streams using Command Line Interface?
  eg 'stream create myKafkaSource1 --definition "kafka --topics=mytopic1 | hdfs" --deploy'.
  
 I could never execute the above command in Spring XD on YARN(ver 1.2)
 
 Alternatively, how do we create a stream(kafka/hdfs) in Spring XD on YARN?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this with ambari deployed XD cluster and then XD on YARN, both worked fine. For yarn I used spring-xd-1.2.1.RELEASE-yarn.zip and just used xd-shell deployed by ambari. I just took settings from a cluster and used ambari's postgred db where I created `xdjob` database with `springxd` user.

My config/servers.yml looked something like this before `bin/xd-yarn push`.

```
xd:
  appmasterMemory: 512M
  adminServers: 1
  adminMemory: 512M
  adminJavaOpts: -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
  adminLocality: false
  containers: 3
  containerMemory: 512M
  containerJavaOpts: -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
  containerLocality: false

spring:
  yarn:
    applicationBaseDir: /xd/yarn/
---
xd:
  container:
    groups: yarn
---
spring:
  yarn:
    siteYarnAppClasspath: "/etc/hadoop/conf,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*"
    siteMapreduceAppClasspath: "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/lib/*"
    config:
      mapreduce.application.framework.path: '/hdp/apps/2.2.6.0-2800/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz#mr-framework'
      mapreduce.application.classpath: '$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/secure'
---
spring:
  hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://ambari-2.localdomain:8020
    resourceManagerHost: ambari-3.localdomain
    resourceManagerPort: 8050
    resourceManagerSchedulerAddress: ambari-3.localdomain:8030
    jobHistoryAddress: ambari-3.localdomain:10020
---
zk:
  namespace: xd
  client:
    connect: ambari-3.localdomain:2181
    sessionTimeout: 60000
    connectionTimeout: 30000
    initialRetryWait: 1000
    retryMaxAttempts: 3

---
xd:
  customModule:
    home: ${spring.hadoop.fsUri}/xd/yarn/custom-modules

---
xd:
  transport: kafka
  messagebus:
    kafka:
      brokers: ambari-2.localdomain:6667
      zkAddress: ambari-3.localdomain:2181

---
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://ambari-1.localdomain/xdjob
    username: springxd
    password: springxd
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    validationQuery: select 1
---
server:
  port: 0
---
spring:
  profiles: admin
management:
  port: 0
```

You can i.e. use `time` source but I used `http` source. Finding correct address use `runtime containers` and `runtime modules` to see where `http` source is running. From `xd-yarn` shell you can use `admininfo` which queries zk to see where xd admin is running. This is needed so that you can connect `xd-shell` to admin running on `yarn`.

```
xd:>admin config server http://ambari-2.localdomain:50254
Successfully targeted http://ambari-2.localdomain:50254
```

Then let's just create kafka streams using sink/source.

```
xd:>stream create httpToKafkaStream --definition "http | kafka --topic=mytopic --brokerList=ambari-2.localdomain:6667" --deploy
xd:>stream create kafkaToHdfsStream --definition "kafka --zkconnect=ambari-3.localdomain:2181 --topic=mytopic --outputType=text/

xd:>http post --target http://ambari-5.localdomain:9000 --data "message1"
xd:>http post --target http://ambari-5.localdomain:9000 --data "message2"
xd:>http post --target http://ambari-5.localdomain:9000 --data "message3"
xd:>http post --target http://ambari-5.localdomain:9000 --data "message4"
xd:>http post --target http://ambari-5.localdomain:9000 --data "message5"

xd:>hadoop fs cat /xd/kafkaToHdfsStream/kafkaToHdfsStream-0.txt
message1
message2
message3
message4
message5
```

NOTE: you need to have `mytopic` created, currently kafka source will fail to start if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Jane, thanks a lot. this helped me to stream kafka source to hdfs sink using Spring XD on YARN(1.2.1). Key thing that I was missing earlier is the following.

Comment: Jane, thanks a lot. This helped me to stream kafka source to hdfs sink using Spring XD on YARN(1.2.1). Key thing that I was missing earlier is the following.   Once Admin server(say http://192.168.60.137:33329) is up and running , we need to open a Spring XD Shell and connect to the admin server using the command 'admin config server http://192.168.60.137:33329'. After that , in the same Spring XD shell,we can create the stream say 'stream create kafkasourcegreat --definition "kafka --zkconnect=192.168.60.136:2181 --topic=kafkasource --outputType=text/plain | hdfs" --deploy'.  Thanks S.Satish